# how can i run the jboss server via windows commands without getting error

Tags: jboss

my java installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin

Jboss server installed in D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin

Already i have set the environment variables for your reference.

C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin

while i started to run the Jboss server7.1 via commands prompts getting error message "JAVA_HOME is not set".

Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this message, set `JAVA_HOME` in `standalone.conf.bat` and `domain.conf.bat` file.

```
rem #
rem # Specify the location of the Java home directory (it is recommended that
rem # this always be set). If set, then "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" will be used as
rem # the Java VM executable; otherwise, "%JAVA%" will be used (see below).
rem #
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\"
```